# Bamboo Spec YAML and location of shared artifacts

Tags: bamboo, bamboo-specs, bamboo-artifacts

in the context of using Gradle to drive build, testing, and further jobs/stages on Bamboo server (**version 7.2.1**) I've configured env. variable `GRADLE_USER_HOME` to save downloaded Gradle binary to project-local path with the intent to share it with further downstream jobs/stages.

But unfortunately Bamboo ignores "source" or `location` folder of the artifact. Excerpt from our `bamboo.yaml`:

```
Build Java application artifact:
  tasks:
    - script:
        scripts:
          - "export GRADLE_USER_HOME=${bamboo.build.working.directory}/GradleUserHome"
          - ./gradlew --no-daemon assemble
          - "echo GRADLE USER HOME content; ls -al $GRADLE_USER_HOME/; echo '---'"  # DEBUG
  artifacts:
    - name: "Gradle Wrapper installation"
      location: GradleUserHome
      pattern: '**/*.*'
      required: true
      shared: true
```

Debugging output of the `echo` command shows expected content.

But next downstream job shows that content of artifact "Gradle Wrapper installation" is installed **relative** to project's workspace, but **not** in sub-folder `./GradleUserHome` as denoted by `location` key (just as if mentioned `location` config item is simply ignored with downstream jobs/stages).

Any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks

PS: Next downstream job exhibits in its log messages something like the following:

```
Preparing artifact 'Gradle Wrapper installation' for use at /var/atlassian/bamboo-agent02-home/xml-data/build-dir/[...] (location: )
```

Take notice of **empty** `location`!